# Unresolved reference: FirebaseTranslateModelManager after updating ML Kit

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-mlkit

I'm using Firebase ML Kit on my app to translate strings. But since I updated my gradle dependencies, some classes can't be found and are marked as unresolved on Android Studio.

This is my `build.gradle` file:

```
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-natural-language:22.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-natural-language-translate-model:20.0.7'
```

This is my code:

```
private val modelManager: FirebaseTranslateModelManager =
        FirebaseTranslateModelManager.getInstance()

// ...

// function to download the models
fun downloadLanguage(language: Language) {
    val model = getModel(FirebaseTranslateLanguage.languageForLanguageCode(language.code))
    modelManager.downloadRemoteModelIfNeeded(model)
        .addOnCompleteListener { fetchDownloadedModels() }
}

// ...

// function to load the downloaded models
private fun fetchDownloadedModels() {
    modelManager.getAvailableModels(FirebaseApp.getInstance())
        .addOnSuccessListener { remoteModels ->
            availableModels.value =
                remoteModels.sortedBy { it.languageCode }.map { it.languageCode }
        }
}
```

Android Studio tells me `FirebaseTranslateModelManager` is unresolved. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

That's because the latest version of ML Kit Translate Text (22.0.0) introduced some breaking changes, as mentioned on the [release notes](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#mlkit-natural-lang_v22-0-0):

> **Breaking change:** Updated `FirebaseTranslateRemoteModel` with the following changes to simplify the developer workflow:
>
> - Removed the `setFirebaseApp` method in Builder. A custom `FirebaseApp` is now supported through the `getInstance` method in `FirebaseModelManager`.
> - Removed the `setDownloadConditions` method in Builder. Download conditions are now passed to the download method in `FirebaseModelManager`.
>
> **Breaking change:** Removed `FirebaseTranslateModelManager`. Translate models are now handled through `FirebaseModelManager`.

So you'll need to update your code to:

```
private val modelManager: FirebaseModelManager = FirebaseModelManager.getInstance()

// ...

fun downloadLanguage(language: Language) {
    val model = getModel(FirebaseTranslateLanguage.languageForLanguageCode(language.code)!!)
    val conditions = FirebaseModelDownloadConditions.Builder()
            .requireWifi()
            .build()
    modelManager.download(model, conditions)
            .addOnCompleteListener { fetchDownloadedModels() }
}

// ...

private fun fetchDownloadedModels() {
    modelManager.getDownloadedModels(FirebaseTranslateRemoteModel::class.java)
            .addOnSuccessListener { remoteModels ->
                availableModels.value =
                        remoteModels.sortedBy { it.languageCode }.map { it.languageCode }
            }
}
```